# JavaScript not loading on XAMPP localhost

Tags: javascript, xampp, localhost

Okay, so when running my HTML and JavaScript through Bracket's live preview, everything works just fine. Yet, when I attempt to run these same scripts on my XAMPP localhost, I get error 404 (the resource files cannot be located). The html and CSS file load just fine, yet the JavaScript file (which is in the same folder) doesn't want to load.

Here's my HTML doc:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href = "main.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div class = "login">
        <input type="text" placeholder= "Pen name">
    </div>
    <div class = "center" id = "error">

    </div>
    <div class = "buttons">
        <a href = "/createrant.html" class = "button" id = "createRantLink">Rant</a>
        <a href = "" class = "button">View Rants</a>
    </div>

    <script src = "/server.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
function backgroundSlideshowOnLoad() {
if (window.location.pathname != "/createrant.html") {
    document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('gif2.gif')"
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('gif1.gif')"
    },2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('gif3.gif')"
    },3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundImage = "url('gif4.gif')"
    },4000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector("html").style.backgroundImage = ""
    },6000);
} else {
    document.body.appendChild(storage)
}
```

window.onload = backgroundSlideshowOnLoad;

and that's my JavaScript file (both are in the same folder)

(p.s. sorry for the bad code i'm new to this)

Comment: Check the folder structure once or try to access the file in separate window like localhost:/js/index.js. If it is accessible, then check the script tag else access issue is there.

Comment: Okay so I tried to change the src to something like "http://localhost/justbetweenus/server.js", yet it still doesn't work even though when I put this link in my browser, it loads the javascript just fine. If it is an access issue how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove slash, it's pointing to root directory

```
<script src = "server.js"></script>
```